# How to force a function to broadcast without invoking `np.vectorize`

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to look for a way to force a function to broadcast.

There are scenarios in which the function/method may be overwritten in a later instance, to constant function. In such case if

```py
arr = np.arange(0, 1, 0.0001)
f = lambda x: 5
f(arr) # this gives just integer 5, i want [5, 5,..., 5]
```

I am aware of methods like `np.vectorize` which force the function to broadcast, but the problem is this is inefficient, as it is essentially for loop under the hood. (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy.vectorize))

We can also use factory methods like `np.frompyfunc` which allows us to transform python function to numpy universal function `ufunc` See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc) for instance. This outperformed `np.vectorize`, but still is way less efficient than builtin `ufunc` methods.

I was wondering if there is any efficient numpy way of handling this, namely to force the function to broadcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a better way to make arbitrary Python functions broadcast, `numpy.vectorize` would use it. You really have to write the function with broadcasting in mind if you want it to broadcast efficiently.

In the particular case of a constant function, you can write a broadcasting constant function using `numpy.full`:

```
def f(x):
    return numpy.full(numpy.shape(x), 5)
```

[`numba.vectorize`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html) can also vectorize functions more effectively than `numpy.vectorize`, but you need Numba, and you need to write your function in a way that Numba can compile efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of `numba` as well. Nonetheless, I was hoping to find something more generic like function wrapper, which I can just put a decorator to those function.

Comment: and a mind reminder: `np.full(shape, val)` takes shape first

Comment: Whoops, that was indeed the wrong argument order. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For those who can live without generic answer, the best answer would be `np.full_like(arr, val)` which improves by about 20% than `np.full(arr.shape, val)`

And after raising this [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13577) to author, I found some best middle ground which achieves both generality while perform rather well:

`np.broadcast_arrays(x, f(x))[1]`

and here are some time analysis:

```py
arr = np.arange(1, 2, 0.0001).reshape(10, -1)

def master_f(x): return np.broadcast_arrays(x, f(x))[-1].copy('K')
def master_f_nocopy(x): return np.broadcast_arrays(x, f(x))[-1]
def vector_f(x): return np.vectorize(f)(x)

%timeit arr+1 # this takes about 10microsec
%timeit master_f(arr) # this takes about 40 mircrosec
%timeit master_f_nocopy(arr) # this takes about 20 microsec
```

Note this allows one to apply to projection functions such as `f(x,y):=y`, which is beyond the help of `np.full_like`.

Moreover, when it comes more complicated function like `np.sin` and `np.cos` you'll notice the difference between `f(arr)` and `master_f_nocopy(arr)` is almost negligible.

Comment: `full_like(arr, val)` takes the dtype from `arr` instead of `val`, though.

Comment: The `broadcast_arrays` approach creates a read-only view of `numpy.asarray(f(x))` where every cell of the view aliases the same cell of the underlying array. This is only okay if you don't need to modify either the result array or the underlying array. (The one where you stuck a `copy` call on the end doesn't have this problem.)